# Why is my stacking regressor scoring worse than its components?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, ensemble-learning

I'm using the following snippet of code:
[image]

The function test_submodels calculates the r^2 testscore of each submodel and tosses out the bad ones (in this case only the svm model), and returns the new list model_names. Then I'm calculating the r^2 scores of my stacked regressor which turns out the be awful. The output of this code can be seen below:
[image: score overview]

Here is some more clarification regarding the submodels, they are created as such:
[image]

Comment: Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original). See why [an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing the problem, I had to define the final estimator in the stacking regressor, for example as such:
[image]

This improves the stacking score to roughly 0.9